# Character Encoding for R%C3%A9f%C3%A9rence

Tags: php

What type of character encoding should I use for this kind of text:

```
R%C3%A9f%C3%A9rence
```

I used htmlentities and utf8_encode but it didn't worked

Comment: Did you tried rawurldecode() ?

Comment: Looks urlencoded. Try urldecode() to get the real characters...

Comment: What do you want to do really? echo urldecode("R%C3%A9f%C3%A9rence"); should convert it back to normal readable text.

Comment: @Code Hunter code `echo urldecode('R%C3%A9f%C3%A9rence');`  print  `Référence`...

Comment: with urldecode I got this R� � f� � rence

Comment: Seems like your document lacks character (no pun intended) to properly display the letters...check my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Think I got an answer for your issues. First make sure your document has the right character set.

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
echo urldecode('R%C3%A9f%C3%A9rence');
```